# ldconfig cache not updated for copied library

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linker, shared-libraries

I would like to make my custom shared library "libfoo.so" listed in system search path.

1, build libfoo.so.1.2 with soname libfoo.so.1
2, copy both into /lib64/ and create linker name syslink for libfoo

```
libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1.2
libfoo.so.1 -> libfoo.so.1.2
libfoo.so.1.2
```

3, run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Note:
    Tried to delete ldconfig cache: ld.so.cache and regenerate, still no luck.
    Reboot and not working
    /lib64/ is listed under /etc/ld.so.conf

however the ldconfig cache does not list libfoo and therefore my app that depends on libfoo will fail.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you try ldconfig -p | grep foo ? what do you see there ?

Comment: Could you please remove `makefile` from your tags list? Your question has nothing to do with make.

Comment: @user2760375 thanks for your reply, I use this command to check if cache is updated with my .so

Answer (score 1):

This is due to our shared library does not following GNU naming convention. lib.so

Without the prefix lib*, ldconfig will not add syslink to cache.